# JAX return types after transformations

Tags: python, jit, autograd, jax

Why is the return type of `jax.grad` different to other `jax` transformations in the following scenario?

Consider a function to be transformed by JAX which takes a custom container as an argument

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from collections import namedtuple

# Define NTContainer using namedtuple factory
NTContainer = namedtuple(
    'NTContainer',['name','flag','array']
)

# Instantiate container
container = NTContainer(
   name='composite-container',
   flag=0,
   array=jnp.reshape(jnp.arange(6,dtype='f4'),(3,2)),
)

# Test function
def test_func(container : NTContainer):
    if container.flag == 0:
        return container.array.sum()
    return container.array.prod()
```

JAX needs to be informed how to handle NTContainer correctly (default `namedtuple` pytree cannot be used)

```
# Register NTContainer pytree to handle static and traceable members

def unpack_NTC(c):
    active, passive = (c.array,), (c.name, c.flag)
    return active, passive

def repack_NTC(passive, active):
    (name, flag), (array,) = passive, active
    return NTContainer(name,flag,value)

jax.tree_util.register_pytree_node(
    NTContainer, unpack_NTC, repack_NTC,
)
```

Now performing several `jax` transforms and calling with `container` results in

```
jax.jit(test_func)(container)
# DeviceArray(15., dtype=float32)

jax.vmap(test_func)(container)
# DeviceArray([1., 5., 9.], dtype=float32)

jax.grad(test_func)(container)
# NTContainer(name='composite-container',
#     flag=0,
#     array=DeviceArray([[1., 1.],
#         [1., 1.],
#         [1., 1.]], dtype=float32))
```

Why does the `jax.grad` transform call return a `NTContainer` rather than a `DeviceArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this is the return value because this is how `grad` is defined, and to be honest I'm not sure how else it could be defined.

Thinking about these transforms;

- `jit(f)(x)` computes the output of `f` applied to `x`: the result is a scalar.
- `vmap(f)(x)` computes the output of `f` applied to each element of the arrays in `x`: the result is a vector.
- `grad(f)(x)` computes the gradient of `f` with respect to each component of `x`, and the result is one value per component of `x`.

So it makes sense that `grad(f)(x)` in this case has to return a collection of multiple values, but how should this collection of gradients be packaged?

JAX could have defined `grad` so that it always returns these as a list or tuple, but this might make it hard to understand how the output gradients relate to the inputs, particularly for more complicated structures like nested lists, tuples, and dicts. So instead JAX takes these per-component gradients and re-bundles them in the same structure as the input argument: therefore, in this case the result is a `NTContainer` containing those per-component gradients.

Comment: Understandable default behaviour; thanks @jakevdp. Since this depends on how the pytree is registered, can this behaviour be controlled when registering a custom tree?

Comment: No, there's not currently any way to customize autodiff behavior for pytrees.

Comment: This suggests the traceable variables should be as explicit as possible for AD. This is reasonable since it's use should be deeper in the code where composite types passed to the main/outer call can be unravelled.